# Overlapping elements with Packery and Infinite Scroll 3

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, packery, imagesloaded

I'm implement in my project packery + Infinite scroll 3, but when I scroll the page, and new items are loaded, these do not respect packery.

```
var grid = document.querySelector('.masonry_base');
var pckry = new Packery( grid, {
  itemSelector: '.post-grid',
  percentPosition: true
});
// layout Packery after each image loads
imagesLoaded( grid ).on( 'progress', function() {
  pckry.layout();
    msnry.options.itemSelector = '.post-grid';
});
var elem = document.querySelector('.masonry_base');
var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( elem, {
  // options
  path: '.next',
  append: '.post-grid',
  history: false,
});
```

How do I make sure that every time new items are loaded through infinite load, imagesLoaded load packery to align the divs?

Here are two screenshots, this is my situation [before](https://pasteboard.co/GzrpdbV.png) loading other items and [after](https://pasteboard.co/GzroCs3.png) loading

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to reload components after the infinite scroll?

Comment: Liam, have you tried using Metafizzy's "imagesLoaded" javascript?: https://packery.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded